# Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence and the subsequence $\{x_{2n}\}$ is convergent. Justify $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

I think I did this correctly:

Since $\{x_{2n}\}$ is convergent, it is bounded. Since $\{x_{2n}\}$ is a bounded subsequence of $\{x_{n}\}$, $\{x_{n}\}$ is also bounded. Hence, $\{x_{n}\}$ is monotone and bounded. Therefore, $\{x_{n}\}$ is convergent by the monotone convergence theorem.

I'm just not sure about this statement: "Since $\{x_{2n}\}$ is a bounded subsequence of $\{x_{n}\}$, $\{x_{n}\}$ is also bounded."

Comment: You're right to be not sure. As it stands, it doesn't imply the boundedness of $\{x_n\}$. You must use the monotonicity for the conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct: Suppose that $M$ is a bound on the sequence $\{x_{2n}\}$. Now if we consider an *odd* number $2k - 1$, then we can say

$$x_{2k - 1} \le x_{2k} \le M$$

by monotonicity. Hence $M$ is a bound on both the even and odd parts of the sequence, thus on the sequence as a whole.

---

But it's *not* true in general that a sequence with a bounded subsequence is bounded; take

$$x_n = \left\{\begin{array}{c} 0 & : n \text{ is even} \\
n & : n \text{ is odd} \end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your hypotheses can be weakened.
Instead of using
$\{x_{2n}\}$,
you can use
$\{x_{n_i}\}$,
where
$(n_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$
is any strictly increasing
sequence of positive integers
(such as $2_i$,
$i^2$,
or
$2^{2^{...^2}}$
with $i$ levels of exponents).